# Upload featured image from front end using media-upload.php

Tags: uploads, post-thumbnails, media, front-end, wp-insert-post

I'm trying to use `admin/upload.php` to upload featured image from front end form.

All I have to do is put below code in the front end form

```
<div id="postimagediv" class="postbox ">
    <div class="handlediv" title="Click to toggle"><br></div>
    <h3 class="hndle ui-sortable-handle"><span>Featured Image</span></h3>
    <div class="inside">
        <p class="hide-if-no-js"><a title="Set featured image" href="http://localhost:8888/WordPress/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=POST_ID&amp;type=image&amp;TB_iframe=1&amp;width=753&amp;height=491" id="set-post-thumbnail" class="thickbox">Set featured image</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

`media-upload.php` seems to be taking care of most of featured image functions (AJAX uploading and remove featured image through AJAX)

The problem is I can't get the `post_id` on front end from before actually submitting the entire form.

below is the only way I can get `post_id` after submitting the form

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Is there a way to give temporary id to the `post_id` and update it when form is submitted?

or get post_id as soon as front end form is loaded? cause I notice when you write post in backend, you immediately get the `post_id` when you click Add New button.